# Microsoft Access Table Shows Up Blank, But Query Correctly Pulls Data From Table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am having an issue with my Microsoft Access database. One of my tables looks completely blank, but it has 11632 records listed in the bottom. Take a look at this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUN2G.png). Though the table shows up blank, when I run the query it pulls the correct data from this table, so I know the data is there, it is just not appearing for some reason. I have tried on Access 2013 and 2016 on a different computer, and both have the same effect. I have also tried compacting and repairing, and also exporting the table but the file it exports to also appears blank, aside from the field names. Any ideas on what I could try?

Thanks!

Comment: Please show the SQL of query as it may not use that table but a similar name. Or it can use that table on a `LEFT JOIN` and so mis-matches do not matter.

Comment: PErhaps you just have a TON of records that are NULL all the way across. Your picture shows, at the bottom, `1 of 11632` suggesting that those records do, in fact, exist. Are they all NULL and your query just obfuscates that issue? Does data start showing up if you scroll down a few hundred/thousand records?

Comment: @JNevill That was the issue.... It's blank all the way down to record 811, then it shows actual data. Would this be a bad import? We append new records from a spreadsheet twice a month, but we do have April's data in there so I'm wondering if it's bits and pieces of bad data along the way or something.

Comment: Sounds like a bad import. Just run a delete statement to clear those out and you'll be set.

Comment: @JagSwag2014 Spreadsheets can be tricky to import unless you specifically set the end row or massage the imported data from a temp table - many times extra blank rows will be added to the import if the people editing the sheet have deleted or inserted rows or done copy/pasting of rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn your import into a 2 step process (or more...).  Write it raw into a scratch pad table.  Then fire an append query, that has the appropriate criteria to result in only valid records going into the final table.

This isn't unusual at all given that some outside data sources may not have the controls to prevent bad records.  Sometimes one must "wash" the data with several different query criteria/steps in order to filter out the bad guys.